# Javascript elementwise array subtraction

Tags: javascript

I would like to use function chaining to subtract one array of arrays... from another of identical dimensions. I undoubtedly have deeper levels of dimensions than are required for my minimal example, so it may look a little odd.

I am relatively new to javascript.

my data structure is:

```js
const data_1 = [["0", ["foo", 10]], ["1", ["bar", 15]], ["2", ["baz", 20]]];
const data_2 = [["0", ["foo", 8]], ["1", ["bar", 17]], ["2", ["baz", 10]]];
```

I would like:

data_result:

```
const data_result = [["0", ["foo", 2]], ["1", ["bar", -2]], ["2", ["baz", 10]]] ;
```

How do I functionally achieve the above?

If these data were not nested in several layers of arrays I could (most likely) use:

```
data_result = data_1.map(function(item,index){return item - data_2[index]})
```

-or equivalently-

```
data_result = data_1.map((n,i) => n - data_2[i]})
```

Any and all help is appreciated.
I will update if I need to clarify something in the question.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `data_2[i]` is also an array, we have to use `[1]` to get the array inside. Then to get the number to subtract, we have to use `[1]` again.

```js
const data_1 = [["0", ["foo", 10]], ["1", ["bar", 15]], ["2", ["baz", 20]]];
const data_2 = [["0", ["foo", 8]], ["1", ["bar", 17]], ["2", ["baz", 10]]];

const data_result = data_1.map(([n, [key, a]], i) => [n, [key, a - data_2[i][1][1]]]);

console.log(data_result);
```

Comment: okay, so all I was missing was a bunch of indexing in. Seems silly for me to miss that in hindsight. I appreciate the answer :)

Comment: For my understanding @caTS , could you explain what "key" is doing/referencing?

Comment: @Skyehawk I'm using destructuring here to simplify the code. The `key` represents the strings `"foo"`, `"bar"`, and `"baz"`. Likewise, `n` has the values `"0"`, `"1"`, and `"1"`. You can use the term "JS destructuring" to find more info about this.